# Are client-side JOINs preferred in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Since server-side joins are not supported in CQL, are client-side joins the preference as a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queries which require joins are not recommended in Cassandra because they don't perform or scale well. If you have to do a JOIN to satisfy an application request, it implies that you didn't get your data model right.

You need to design your data model such that each app query maps to one table. If you have to do a client-side JOIN it means that you had to query the database multiple times to get the data. It may work for you but it will never perform as well as making a single read request to one table. Cheers!

Comment: "*If you have to do a JOIN to satisfy an application request, it implies that you didn't get your data model right*" - Or alternatively the data model is correct for their use cases but they chose the wrong database system. Either way, fair point, upvoted.